# Load two dimensional array from xml file

Tags: java, arrays, xml

So I hava a a two dimensional array of objects which I can store into an XML file using encoder.writeObject. Now I want to load the stored Array back into a new array.

```
data = new Object[][]{
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"},
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"},
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"},
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"}
        };
```

```
encoder.writeObject(data);
```

now i want to read the file with this method:

```
data = decoder.readObject();
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must try with below code:

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)){
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(fis);
            Object[][] data = (Object[][]) decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();
            return data;
        }
```

Entire code:

```
import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "data.xml";
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"},
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"},
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"},
                new String[] {"youtube", "max", "mail.com", "password"}
        };
        serializeToXML(data,fileName);
        Object[][] xmlData = deserializeFromXML(fileName);
        for (Object[] xmlDatum : xmlData) {
            for (Object xmlDataun : xmlDatum) {
                System.out.print(xmlDataun.toString()+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

    }

    private static void serializeToXML (Object[][] data,String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName)){
            try(XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(fos)){
                encoder.writeObject(data);
            }
        }

    }
    private static Object[][] deserializeFromXML(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)){
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(fis);
            Object[][] data = (Object[][]) decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();
            return data;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I was searching for. i didn't knew how to use the method readObject correctly.

Comment: @Lennart4711 Then can you accept this answer.